# Get arguments passed to powershell.exe

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to determine, in a Profile script, what arguments were passed to the powershell executable?

### Use-case

I'd like to check whether the WorkingDirectory parameter was set, before overriding it with my own `cd` in my user profile.

### Attempts

I've made a few helpless attempts to get variable values from within the profile script, with no luck. None of them seem to give me any information about whether `pwsh.exe` was invoked with a `-wd` parameter or not:

```
echo $PSBoundParameters
echo $ArgumentList
echo (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 0).Value;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To **inspect PowerShell's own invocation command line**, you can use:

- `[Environment]::CommandLine` (single string)
- or `[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()` (array of arguments, including the executable as the first argument).

These techniques also work on Unix-like platforms.

*Caveat*: As of PowerShell Core 7 (.NET Core 3.1), it is `pwsh.dll`, not `pwsh[.exe]` that is reported as the executable.

---

**To check in your `$PROFILE` file if a working directory was specified on startup** could look like this, though do note that the solution is not foolproof:

```
$workingDirSpecified =
  ($PSVersionTable.PSEdition -ne 'Desktop' -and
   [Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs() -match '^-(WorkingDirectory|wd|wo|wor|work|worki|workin|working|workingd|workingdi|workingdir|workingdire|workingdirec|workingdirect|workingdirecto|workingdirector)') -or
  [Environment]::CommandLine -match
    '\b(Set-Location|sl|cd|chdir|Push-Location|pushd|pul)\b'
```

- In PowerShell Core, a working directory may have been specified with the `-WorkingDirectory` / `-wd` parameter (which isn't supported in Windows PowerShell); e.g.,
  `pwsh -WorkingDirectory /`

  - Note: Given that it is sufficient to specify only a *prefix* of a parameter's name, as long as that prefix uniquely identifies the parameter, it is necessary to also test for `wo`, `wor`, `work`, ...
- In both PowerShell Core and Windows PowerShell, the working directory may have been set with a cmdlet call (possibly via a built-in alias) as part of a `-c` / `-Command` argument (e.g.,
  `pwsh -NoExit -c "Set-Location /"`)

  - Note: In this scenario, unlike with `-WorkingDirectory`, the working directory has *not* yet been changed at the time the `$PROFILE` file is loaded.

It is possible, but unlikely for the above to yield false positives; to use a contrived example:
`pwsh -NoExit -c "'Set-Location inside a string literal'"`

Answer (score 2):

How about (powershell.exe or pwsh.exe?):

```
get-ciminstance win32_process | where name -match 'powershell.exe|pwsh.exe' | 
  select name,commandline
```

Comment: I'd use `Where-Object ProcessId -eq $PID` instead of  `where name -match …`. BTW, the `WorkingDirectory` parameter is valid for `pwsh` but invalid for `powershell`.